# Run service operation on a different thread than the service thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, wcf

I'm working on a WinForms application that will contain a `WebBrowser` and will act as a service for another process. I'd like to implement a `NavigateAndWait` method, but apparently, when I invoke my service's (my WinForms application) methods from the client, this methods run in the same thread or somehow in synchronization with the service's UI thread. This is what I have so far:

Service:

```
public class Browser : IBrowser
{
    private bool _Navigating = false;

    public bool Navigating
    {
        get { return _Navigating; }
    }

    public Browser()
    {
        ServiceForm.Instance.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Url == ServiceForm.Instance.webBrowser1.Url) _Navigating = false;
    }

    public void Navigate(string url)
    {
        _Navigating = true;
        ServiceForm.Instance.webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse/PipeReverse");
        NetNamedPipeBinding pipeBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
        ChannelFactory<IBrowser> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IBrowser>(pipeBinding, endpointAddress);
        IBrowser browser = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
        browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        while (browser.Navigating) { }
        MessageBox.Show("done!");
    }
```

This works OK other than my client will freeze for a little while (literally!). I could easily run `button1_Click` on another thread in my client, but what I'd really want to do is implement my `NavigateAndWait` (which would basically be the last three lines of code in the `button1_Click` method) in my service. But I've tried this and it never returns, apparently because the `DocumentComplete` event handler never gets called because I'm inside the `while` loop running in the service's UI thread.

So my question is how can I tell WCF to run my service's operation on a thread other than the UI thread so I can do my `while` loop in that *other* thread?

Comment: Bad: "while (browser.Navigating) { }"

Comment: @Steve: what should I use instead (considering I'm trying to write a `NavigateAndWait` method)?

Comment: Put an event on your IBrowser interface, and invoke it from your `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` method?

Comment: That wouldn't be a `NavigateAndWait` method. I know how to use the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` event, but as you can see I'm trying to wrap around it, kinda like the `WaitN` library does.

Comment: You intentionally want to spin lock the main thread? Doesn't seem like a good idea. If you want to wait the thread, you should look into the Thread Synchronization primitives .NET has for you instead of trying to spin lock with a while loop. I'm glad you decided to delete the comment about me wasting your time.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964.aspx Use a Wait Handle (`ManualResetEvent`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)

Comment: "You intentionally want to spin lock the main thread?". Did you read the whole question? Locking the main thread is not my point, but as I said several times, writing a `NavigateAndWait` method, which could be called from a thread other than the main thread. Regarding the wasting my time comment, yea I decided it was a little rough. But I think is pretty obvious that my code above is just a test code. I don't see your point on picking on it without giving an alternative (other than the "not doing what I'm trying to do" alternative).

Comment: @Steve: Yes, that's an alternative. I'll dig into that as soon as I figure out this other problem (the WCF thing).

Comment: Your question specifically states that your intention is to spin lock the main thread: `So my question is how can I tell WCF to run my service's operation on a thread other than the UI thread so I can do my while loop in there?`

Comment: I want to do my `while` (which will most likely be replaced for a `Wait` handle later on) in a thread _other_ than the UI thread. "in there" here means in the "other thread". I probably wasn't clear enough. My bad :).

Comment: If you'd fix the problem I pointed out, your life will get a lot easier. Take the advice, or don't, I don't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `UseSynchronizationContext = false` option in the `[ServiceBehavior]` attribute in your service. That will tell WCF not to enforce the posting of all requests to the thread where it was created (in your case, the UI thread). That attribute would go in the service **class** (not the interface).

Comment: Does this _not to enforce_ means it sill might run on the UI thread, or will if force it not to?

Comment: OK this worked. Just need to make sure it will never run on the service's UI thread (unless I call it from the UI thread, of course). Do you know if this is the case?